# Launching Jade In Ubuntu10.04 Linux

Tags: java, ubuntu, agents-jade

When I run the below command in terminal of ubuntu linux and also I set the ClassPath properly but I wasn't successful.

```
java jade.Boot -gui
```

I got following errors in terminal window:

```
15 Jun, 2011 6:33:10 PM jade.core.Runtime beginContainer
INFO: ----------------------------------
    This is JADE snapshot - revision 6357 of 2010/07/06 16:27:34
        downloaded in Open Source, under LGPL restrictions,
        at http://jade.tilab.com/
----------------------------------------
Retrieving CommandDispatcher for platform null
15 Jun, 2011 6:33:11 PM jade.imtp.leap.CommandDispatcher addICP
WARNING: Error adding ICP jade.imtp.leap.JICP.JICPPeer@ae506e[Error: Not possible to     launch JADE on a remote host (127.0.1.1). Check the -host and -local-host options.].
15 Jun, 2011 6:33:11 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl joinPlatform
SEVERE: Communication failure while joining agent platform: No ICP active
jade.core.IMTPException: No ICP active
    at jade.imtp.leap.LEAPIMTPManager.initialize(LEAPIMTPManager.java:138)
    at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.init(AgentContainerImpl.java:316)
    at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.joinPlatform(AgentContainerImpl.java:482)
    at jade.core.Runtime.createMainContainer(Runtime.java:165)
    at jade.Boot.main(Boot.java:89)
15 Jun, 2011 6:33:11 PM jade.core.Runtime$1 run
INFO: JADE is closing down now.
```

help me to recover from this error.

Comment: This needs to be asked on the sister-site, askubuntu.com.

Comment: The question needs to be improved, but not moved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am so tired of this problem. It is one of many quirks and problems with JADE.

The problem you are facing is that you  need to supply correct host information in the command line. Example

java jade.Boot -gui -local-host

This is all described here: http://jade.tilab.com/doc/tutorials/JADEAdmin/startJade.html

In many cases you don't have this problem and then it is sufficient to use the -gui option only. However I have discovered that Jade does not work very well when your  resolves to 127.0.1.1. You can fix this by setting your IP address in  or if you are on Linux edit your /etc/hosts file for a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 4):

just type in JADE path..

```
java -cp lib/jade.jar jade.Boot -gui -local-host 127.0.0.1
```

(JADE has some problems to set local host adress)

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be is previous java process might be still running on the local port , Make sure to check if port is in use  or not if in use kill the java process before you rerun.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple.

Modify /etc/hosts

Modify the line for the address 127.0.0.1, as follows:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost <machine_name>

Remove or comment the line with 127.0.1.1:

> # 127.0.1.1 <machine_name>

and you're done.

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is an English Q&A site. You HAVE to write your answer and questions in English. I have attempted to translate it for you, but next time your answer might simply be removed.

Answer (score 0):

**The error isn't in the jade**. **It's** a bug used by jade to start the default parameters with **a bugged java method that should be fixed**.

**When jade runs the java method, it will retrieve `127.0.1.1` instead the loop-back `127.0.0.1`**.

I'm saying it because I tested. I read the JADE src that do this and I executed the java method that I didn't remember now.

Unfortunately it's happening in a few linux machines. In windows I didn't see it happens.

What I did to solve this problem was to edit the /etc/hosts file, like this:

Original file:

```
 127.0.0.1 localhost
 127.0.1.1 machine-name
```

Modified file:

```
 127.0.0.1 localhost machine-name
 127.0.1.1 machine-name
```

What I did was to put an alias of the machine-name on the loop-back ip address. This will bypass the bug.